# RegEx to capture all text except certain tags

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I have a string such as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <foo attr="something">consectetur adipisicing elit</foo>, sed do eiusmod <bar>tempor incididunt</bar> ut labore et dolore <baz>magna aliqua</baz>.
```

I'm looking to get all the text that's not part of a selected subset of tags.  In this example, `<foo>` and `<bar>` tags only.  I don't expect to be able to do this with one regular expression, I need some JS code which will let me manipulate the text outside of those specific tags, and then to re-constitute the entire string, modified.

For example, let's say that I want to replace all letter a's with *.  The desired output would be:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit *met, <foo attr="something">consectetur
*dipisicing elit</foo>, sed do eiusmod <bar>tempor incididunt</bar> ut l*bore et dolore <b*z>magn* *liqu*</b*z>.
```

Note how the `<baz>` tag has been modified.

Comment: <Sigh>. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good enough at RegExp to putting together something like that.  I will say, however, [to not parse HTML with RegExp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).

I suggest you look at parsing / filtering with an XML parser.  You could use JS' native DOM tools to do what you want:

1. Create a [`document fragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) from your `container` node
2. Within the `document fragment`, delete the nodes you want to filter out
3. Replace the `original container` with your `document fragment`